# Bug report: ScrollStrategies does not work when LineSeries consists of the same numbers

Tags: javascript, lightningchart, bug-reporting

After building a chart and adding a series to it with the same data set, such as

```
const dataSet = [
       {x: 400, y: 0},
       {x: 400, y: 1},
       {x: 400, y: 2},
       {x: 400, y: 3},
       {x: 400, y: 4},
       {x: 400, y: 5},
       {x: 400, y: 6},
    ]
```

AutoScrolling does not occur, and axis mouse events do not work.
I used the chrome tools and may have found the problem.
[image]

The Li function in the case when the minimum and maximum LineSeries value returns true and the Cr function returns undefined. Perhaps this is the expected behavior, I don't know.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you described is related to all the data points having the exact same X value (400). Automatic scrolling doesn't behave all too well in my experience when the data set has "empty boundaries" (in this case, minimum X = maximum X = 400).

PS.
obfuscated code debugging doesn't give useful information to our direction, and I would assume that it isn't too worthwhile for you either :)

Comment: I completely agree with you. I wanted to understand what the problem is and solve it in my code